# How to find all first-week days(days up to first Sunday) of the month(date is provided) in the SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find all first-week(days up to first Sunday) dates when any date of that month is provided to you.

*Example 1*

Given date:

```
2020-04-29
```

Expected Result of Select Query:

```
The first week of April 2020
-----------------------------------------------------
2020-04-01
2020-04-02
2020-04-03
2020-04-04
2020-04-05
```

*Example 2*

Given date:

```
2020-03-29
```

Expected Result of Select Query:

```
The first week of March 2020
-----------------------------------------------------
2020-03-01
```

Comment: How do YOU define "first week"?

Comment: As you answered below, I was expecting all days up to the first Sunday of the month. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all days before the first Monday in the month, then you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
     select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth('2020-04-29', -1)) as dte
     union all
     select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
     from dates 
     where datename(weekday, dte) <> 'Sunday'
)
select *, datename(weekday, dte)
from dates;
```

This assumes that you want 7 days when the week starts on a Monday (although it is easily tweaked to handle that to return no rows.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d817d3898e368db6d3fdabfb9098b9c) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive approach :

```
with r_cte as (
     select dateadd(day, 1,  eomonth('2020-04-29', -1)) as start_dt, dateadd(day, 5, convert(date, EOMONTH('2020-04-29', -1))) as first_wk
     union all
     select dateadd(day, 1, start_dt), first_wk
     from r_cte 
     where start_dt < first_wk
)
select start_dt as first_week
from r_cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function that returns a table, like this one :

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION F_FIRST_N_WEEKDATES (@A_DATE DATETIME2, @N TINYINT)
RETURNS @T TABLE (D DATE)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @D DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@A_DATE), MONTH(@A_DATE), 1);
WHILE @N > 0
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @T VALUES (@D);
   SELECT @D = DATEADD(day, 1, @D), @N-=1;
END
RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Sample :

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.F_FIRST_N_WEEKDATES('2020-04-29', 5)
```

give :

```
D
----------
2020-04-01
2020-04-02
2020-04-03
2020-04-04
2020-04-05
```

Comment: The question is : can the "first" week be partially include in the month or totally ?

Comment: I don't think the fact that there are 5 weekdays in the example was intended to be a constant. He almost certainly stopped at 5 because the 5th April was a Sunday.

Comment: How could I know that I need to pass 5 to the function(i.e. number of days in the first week)?  What if the first week has only one day? (e.g. The first week of March 2020, in this case, I would want 2020-03-01 as a result)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use while function to print out dates.

For getting results in single select statement. You can insert date values in temp table

```
DECLARE @counter int = 1;
DECLARE @date date = '2020-04-29'

WHILE @counter <= 7
BEGIN
    select datefromparts(year(@date), month(@date), @counter); 
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION F_FIRST_WEEKDATES (@A_DATE DATETIME2)
RETURNS @T TABLE (D DATE)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @D DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@A_DATE), MONTH(@A_DATE), 1), @N TINYINT = 1;
WHILE @N < 8 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @T VALUES (@D);
   SELECT @D = DATEADD(day, 1, @D), @N+=1;
   IF DATEPART(weekday, @D) = 1
      BREAK
END
RETURN;
END;
GO
```